# table exceed on containers wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So below I have 2 test, first one has a auto width while the second one has a fixed width (specified width given through a window load event) and both has a style of 'overflow auto'. Is there a way I could automatically make the table get inside its container div and not exceed its parent div width like it reject the behaviour of a child over its parent container?. I prefer not to specified the width of the parent just to simply fix the problem (it must be auto width to cater its responsiveness). Any help, clues, suggestions, ideas, recommendations are greatly appreciated, thank you.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  //set the width of the #test2
  $("#test2").css({ 'width' : $("#test2_wrapper").width() + 'px', 'margin' : '0px auto' });
  alert("#test2 div, has a width of "+$("#test2_wrapper").width()+"px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div style="overflow:auto;width:100%;border:1px solid blue;">
  <h3>Without specifying width on the container</h3>
<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Real Password</td>
        <td>Firstname</td>
        <td>Middlename</td>
        <td>Lastname</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Martial Status</td>
        <td>Civil Staus</td>
        <td>Mother's Maiden Name</td>
        <td>Father's name</td>
        <td>Contact number incase of emergency</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>STTR</td>
        <td>BIR</td>
        <td>SSS</td>
        <td>Identity number</td>
        <td>Student ID number</td>
        <td>Employee number</td>
        <td>Have you ever tried taco</td>
        <td>Will this is a test to see the tables full length</td>
        <td>Will, the world aint no sunshine and rainbows</td>
        <td>If you dont work hard, you'll end up in a lossers corner</td>
        <td>This is the end of the test</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<div id="test2_wrapper" style="width:600px;border:1px solid red;">
  <h3>With specifying width on the container</h3>
<div style="overflow:auto;border:1px solid pink;" id="test2">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Real Password</td>
        <td>Firstname</td>
        <td>Middlename</td>
        <td>Lastname</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Martial Status</td>
        <td>Civil Staus</td>
        <td>Mother's Maiden Name</td>
        <td>Father's name</td>
        <td>Contact number incase of emergency</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>STTR</td>
        <td>BIR</td>
        <td>SSS</td>
        <td>Identity number</td>
        <td>Student ID number</td>
        <td>Employee number</td>
        <td>Have you ever tried taco</td>
        <td>Will this is a test to see the tables full length</td>
        <td>Will, the world aint no sunshine and rainbows</td>
        <td>If you dont work hard, you'll end up in a lossers corner</td>
        <td>This is the end of the test</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `class="overflow:auto;"` and  `class="overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;"`?

Comment: `.table{overflow:hidden; max-width:980px;} .table td{width:100px;}`. Just an example.

Comment: @PHPglue: sorry, it should be style not class.

Comment: Do you know that you can use the bootstraps grid system to solve the issue??

Comment: @dvenkatsagar: I don't have any idea about that.

Comment: I mean this : https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ and this https://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Comment: yes i agree with dvenkatsagar - You are using bootstrap css but not taking any advantage of it. Use Bootstrap Grid system - http://plnkr.co/edit/Js1b6iYByJir3eTiDE2k?p=preview